# Migrating Apache to another machine

Tags: apache, migrating

I am using apache version 2.0.16 on opensolaris machine.I have one application running on it.Now I want to copy all the configurations files from this to another machine which has the same configuration as the first machine.
For this I would need to copy the httpd.conf file.Are there any other files or configurations I need to copy or write.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Usually http.conf includes other files. You should open it and check for includes.

Some common includes:

- extra/http-*.conf
- sites-available/*

Comment: Can you please tell me the files..which i need to copy.

Comment: All included usually (just in case). Practically, only those about your website.